# Mapping null source values into destination

Tags: automapper

When mapping a source instance to a destination instance, how are null source values handled?  It appears that with built in types, a null source value will overwrite a destination value (set it to null).  However with a navigation property, a destination value will not be set to null by a null source value, e.g. OuterDest.Innter:

`

```
        public class OuterSource
        {
            public int Value { get; set; }
            public InnerSource? Inner { get; set; }
        }

        public class InnerSource
        {
            public int OtherValue { get; set; }
        }

        public class OuterDest
        {
            public int Value { get; set; }
            public InnerDest? Inner { get; set; }
        }

        public class InnerDest
        {
            public int OtherValue { get; set; }
        }
```

`

This test will fail

```
       [TestMethod]
        public void NestedTestNullSourceValue()
        {
            var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterDest>();
                cfg.CreateMap<InnerSource, InnerDest>();
            });

            var mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();

            OuterSource source = new()
            {
                Value = 123
            };

            OuterDest dest = new()
            {
                Value = 888,
                Inner = new()
                {
                    OtherValue = 999
                }
            };

            mapper.Map(source, dest);
            Assert.AreEqual(123, dest.Value);
            Assert.IsNull(dest.Inner);
        }
```

Comment: If you're using AM 12, Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/4130#issuecomment-1302379825

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue ([AutoMapper - Map(source, destination) overwrite destination child object with null value from source via configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74364259/automapper-mapsource-destination-overwrite-destination-child-object-with-nu/74371402#74371402)), updating to AutoMapper 12.0.1 pre-release solved my issue